# Movie about a worm hole that requires a lot of energy to open, but doesn't seem to work

Tags: story-identification, movie, wormhole

I saw the ending of a movie with a lady about to sit in this massive machine in the shape of a loop/circle that looked to be discovered on earth. They had to draw massive amounts of energy to get it to go.

When it did, she seemed to travel through space/time with an alien or being narrating about time/space. Only to be woken up with the scientist saying nothing happened due to a machine error.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like [Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(1997_American_film)):

> lady about to sit in this massive machine in the shape of a loop/circle that looked to be discovered on earth

*Outfitted with several recording devices, Arroway enters the machine's pod, which is then dropped into three rapidly spinning gimbaled rings*

> Only to be woken up with the scientist saying nothing happened due to a machine error.

*Arroway falls unconscious as she begins traveling back through a wormhole. She awakens to find herself on the floor of the pod, the mission control team repeatedly hailing her. She learns that, from outside the machine, it appears that the pod merely dropped through the machine's rings and landed in a safety net.*

Comment: This is _definitely_ *Contact*. :)

Comment: It definitely is. Thanks heaps! :)

Comment: Be sure to click to accept the answer.